# How do I can hide the schema model in Swagger?

Tags: java, swagger-ui, playframework-2.5

To a request unanswered, I want to hide this field (Model schema).

[my swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKuOs.png)

My request

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Create node")
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(paramType = "body", required = true)
})
public Result insert()
```

I do not want to show the **response** attribute in @ApiOperation. It's possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far? What is the problem ? Take a look at the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour for a better understanding of how SO works.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. I don't see any "response" attribute in your code nor your screenshot. What are you expecting the content to look like?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking. However, if you are trying to hide a particular field from the model in the JSON response, try `JsonIgnore` annotation from fasterxml's jackson-annotations module. Just add the annotation to the field you are trying avoid in your Response.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you do not say, I trust based on your post at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play/pull/76#issuecomment-224287765 that you are using Play Framework. I believe a "void" result is broken in swagger-play currently (ref: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play/issues/89). One way I did it (in Scala) was to provide `responseReference = "void"` in the `@ApiOperation` and do the following as my Scala controller to show the Swagger spec to override it with my changes:

```scala
package controllers

import controllers.SwaggerBaseApiController
import io.swagger.models.auth.{ApiKeyAuthDefinition, BasicAuthDefinition, In}
import io.swagger.models.properties.RefProperty
import io.swagger.models.{Info, Response}
import play.api.mvc.Action

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object Swagger extends SwaggerBaseApiController {

  def json = Action { implicit request =>
    val swagger = getResourceListing(request.host)
    // We need to modify this if it doesn't contain our security definitions yet, but we have to do it atomically
    // This should be fast enough that this synchronization is not too bad
    swagger.synchronized {
      if (!somethingThreadSafeToShowYouveChangedItAlready) fixSwagger(swagger)
    }
    // We trust that the above code only changes a swagger instance once therefore we don't need to
    // synchronize the json marshalling because it should not change beneath it
    returnValue(request, toJsonString(swagger))
  }

  private[this] def fixSwagger(swagger: io.swagger.models.Swagger): Unit = {
    // Omitted some of my other changes...

    swagger.getPaths.values.foreach { value =>

      value.getOperations.foreach { oper =>
        // Omitted some of my other chabnges

        // Any responses that are void need to be simple void
        oper.getResponses.values.foreach { resp =>
          resp.getSchema() match {
            case schema: RefProperty if schema.get$ref() == "#/definitions/void" => resp.setSchema(null)
            case _ => ()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide all controller API

```
  @ApiIgnore
```

Hide selected attribute

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = false, hidden = true)
```

Example : Visible

```
@ApiModelProperty(
        access = "public",
        name = "amount",
        example = "123.45",
        value = "the amount - in this example without currency.")
public String getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
```

Example : Hide

```
@ApiModelProperty(
       required = false,
       hidden = true
    )
public String getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
```